# Save changes to Visualforce page in detail page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Visualforce page that has been added to the detail layout. When I make changes to files in the visualforce page the save button is not enabled. It does happen for any other field added to the layout be using the drap and drop method.

I am using the standar controller with no extension and the following code for each field:

```
 <apex:outputField value="{!Installation__c.Serial_Number_1__c}">
   <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
 </apex:outputField>
```

I know I can add a save button but that is not what I need.

Comment: is there a reason why you do not want to have save and edit button, then with a showonedit and hideonEdit you can show/hide the button

Comment: I am not familiar with what you mention, can you ellaborate? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to display/use the standard pages save button from the embedded visualforce page.

Comment: @Daniel Are you trying to have a page that you want to save by using standard page's save button? If this is what you are trying, you cannot since standard pages and VF pages are hosted in different domains.

Comment: My goal is to use a grid for some fields, I tried using a VF and embedding but the height of the generated Iframe is too small so it doesn't show the entire grid.